# Discord.js Ban User Permissions Command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So whenever a moderator on my server uses the ban command, they can ban moderators and admins. Is there a way to fix this with permissions? Basically, I want it so when a moderator uses the ban command, they can't ban an admin. Some people told me a solution is to move the role down, but I want to keep the role above my admin role. Here is my ban code:

```
const { MODLOGCHANNELNAME, MUTEROLE, MAINROLE, PREFIX, BOTNAME} = require("../config.json");
var ms = require('ms');
var Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports ={
  name: 'ban',
  aliases: ['b',],//'@Knife Guard 2.0'],
  description: 'Bans a user from this server',
  usage: 'ban [mention] [reason]',
  category: "moderation",

  execute: async (message, args, client) => {
    
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();

    if(!message.member.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS", "ADMINISTRATOR"])) return message.channel.send("You do not have permission to perform this command!");

    let banMember = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
    if(!banMember) return message.channel.send("Please provide a user to ban!");

    var reason = args.splice(1).join(' ');
    if(!reason) return message.reply('You need to give a reason!'); 

    if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS", "ADMINISTRATOR"])) return message.channel.send("I dont have permission to perform this command");
    //message.delete();

    var bot_name = BOTNAME;

    let dmEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#FF0000')
      .setTitle('You Are Banned')
      .addField('Reason:', reason, true)
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      .setFooter(bot_name)
      .setTimestamp();

    message.channel.send(`**${banMember.user.tag}** has been banned`);//.then(m => m.delete(5000));

    banMember.send(dmEmbed).then(() => //dms the user they r banned
    // banMember.send(`Hello, you have been banned from ${message.guild.name} for: ${reason}`).then(() => //dms the user they r banned
    message.guild.member(banMember).ban(banMember, {reason: reason, days: 1})); //once DM done, Ban member
   

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    var banEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#FF0000')
    .setAuthor(`${message.guild.name} Modlogs`, message.guild.iconURL)
    .addField('Moderation:', "Ban")
    .addField("Moderated On:", `${user.username} (${user.id})`)
    .addField("Moderator", message.author.username)
    .addField("Reason:", reason)
    .setTimestamp()
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    .setFooter(bot_name, message.author.avatarURL());
    
    let modlogchannel = (`${MODLOGCHANNELNAME}`);
    var channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === modlogchannel); 
    channel.send(banEmbed);

  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare both members' highest roles to each other with [`Role.comparePositionsTo()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=comparePositionTo)

> Returns a negative number if this role's position is lower (other role's is higher), positive number if this one is higher (other's is lower), 0 if equal

```js
// message author's highest role
const authorRole = message.member.roles.highest;

// target's highest role
const targetRole = banMember.roles.highest;

// if targetRole's position is higher or equal to authorRole's
if (targetRole.comparePositionsTo(authorRole) <= 0)
  return message.channel.send(...);
```

Comment: is there a way I can add a second role to it? Like If I had a role called protected? thanks!

Comment: Just replace `targetRole` with whatever role you'd like to compare positions.